# Programatically position the label (left,top)

Tags: delphi

Maybe trivial (or asked before but cant see similar questions because my browser garbles them all),
but how do you position a label programmatically to a position of left or top ?

Comment: To align the *control*, you can position it manually and set its `Anchors`, or you can set its `Align` property (works OK for top and bottom). To set the alignment of the text inside the control, use `Alignment` for horisontal alignment and `Layout` for vertical alignment. (This assumes VCL.) In this case, you probably want to disable `AutoSize`.

Comment: Or do you mean entirely manually? If so, just set the `Left` and `Top` properties.

Comment: I know I can do it manually but I am interested in programmatically...

Comment: The answer is exactly the same. All these properties are available at runtime. (E.g. `Label1.Top := 20; Label1.Left := 20`. You didn't say *when* you want to do it, but in the form's `OnCreate` handler would work. Or in a button's `OnClick` handler. In some cases, you want to do it in the form's `OnResize`.)

Comment: thenk you andreas...

Comment: "my browser garbles them all"  Sounds like you should fix your browser or use another one.  Googling `delphi set tlabel position site:stackoverflow.com` works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andreas Rejbrand gave you the explanations in his comments. To be clear, here is actual code example positioning a label right above a button. I also set the visible property to TRUE so that the label becomes visible.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Label1.Left    := Button1.Left;
    Label1.Top     := Button1.Top - Label1.Height;
    Label1.Visible := TRUE;
end;
```